# Lazy Loading for multiple UITableView in one view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am working on iPad app. And I am using 2 tables in one view and images urls are coming from 
web services. I am using Apple provided lazy loading for both tables, and there are 2 web-service called for showing the two tables data, one is calling in `ViewDidLoad`() and second is calling in callback method of first web service. And I am facing problem in this method.

```
- (void)appImageDidLoad:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath withDataReceived:(NSData*)receivedData
```

The values for indexpath.row values are changing every time , some time it gives correct value and some time not.
Can anybody please help me for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the related code and what is the use of appImageDidLoad method ?

Answer (score 0):

you might have to pass in which tableview also.. you kno how it is passing indexPath to that method.. modify it to pass tableview.. and inside the method.. check which tableView and then get the right data source array for appropriate tableview..